# USB GPS Accuracy

Tags: usb, gps

This afternoon I tested an AmbiCom USB GPS and the cordinates were jumping all over. Most of them were at least 30 feet off. Anyone have any experience with any other brands/have any recommendations for a more accurate USB GPS unit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is normal for a GPS receiver. The accuracy will, like davr, already said, depend on the obstacles in all directions, speed of movement, ...

If you need a higher level of accuracy you'll have to go with differential GPS.

Answer (score 1):

30 feet is 10 meters, that's about normal for standard GPS. Were you indoors, outdoors, are there any buildings around, etc? The very best I've ever gotten on my GPS is an accuracy of 9 feet (3 meters), and that's only outdoors with a completely clear sky in all directions.

What are you using it for that you need better than 30 foot accuracy?